# Mixed conditionals and inversion

Tags: inversion, conditionals

I've been trying to play around with **mixed conditional clauses** and **inversion**. These topics are obviously not the easiest ones, so I have experienced some issues.

**My sentence**:

> Weren’t professionals from Amazon to ***explore*** AI and deep learning so vigorously, these vital spheres of science wouldn’t have gone mainstream, gaining popularity and ubiquity.

First off, I am not entirely sure that this sentence is correct. Secondly, I would like to show that the process of ***exploring*** is continuous. However, I’ve read that you have to replace if with were and change the verb to the infinitive with “to” (2nd conditional). Without inversion it is quite straightforward (I guess): “If they weren't exploring …”. Could you please help me out? I can’t get my head around it.

Comment: briefly, consider "Were professionals from Amazon not to be exploring AI and deep learning so vigorously, ..."

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that your question is even more complicated than your sentence.

Comment: I think you should avoid the contraction here; sounds weird to me - "be" is an important word there

Comment: And just for a little more info, "Were professionals from Amazon not to have been exploring AI...

Comment: Justin Stafford, thanks a million. Without contraction and with "to be exploring" it definitely sounds like a correct sentence. Can you please elaborate a little bit more on replacing the rule ***... the verb to the infinitive with “to”*** with ***to have been exploring***. Can I actually use any appropriate time after “to”? I mean, can it be not only infinitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Weren’t professionals from Amazon to explore AI and deep learning so vigorously, these vital spheres of science wouldn’t have gone mainstream, gaining popularity and ubiquity.

You can't use a contraction like "weren't" as part of conditional inversion.

(With a simple statement, the word order "I was not ..." becomes "Was I not?" in a question - one only rarely comes across "Was not I?", but the contraction "Wasn't I?" is perfectly normal.  However, with a conditional inversion, the negative form "Were I not ..." does not get contracted to "Weren't I".)

"Were ... not to have explored" or (as someone suggested) "were ... not to have been exploring" might *just about* be acceptable, but they still sound awkward - and to my mind we are discussing a hypothetical past, so the past perfect is appropriate for the condition clause.

The correct sentence would be:

> **Had** professionals from Amazon **not** explored AI and deep learning so vigorously, ...

(inverted from "If professionals from Amazon had not explored...").

This would also work:

> **Had** professionals from Amazon **not been** exploring AI and deep learning so vigorously, ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that "weren't" is not acceptable at all. In fact, I've already quit using contractions when it comes to inversion :)

Comment: I've thought about using the 3rd conditional, but I want to convey the idea that they have been working (they were and they are working). "Were I not so shy, I would have married her a long time ago". I am shy, and I didn’t marry her. In this case, my personality trait – shyness – is a part of my nature (it’s timeless, sort of. I was and I am shy), so it makes sense to use “if I were not so shy” instead of “if I had not been so shy”. And I am wondering whether it is possible to use the same logic with regard to continuous actions such as “were working”. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, you could say "If professionals from Amazon were not exploring ..." and combine it with "these vital spheres wouldn't have been..." in the result clause.  In this case, I would avoid the inverted form "Were professionals from Amazon not exploring ...", though - but I can't currently put my finger on why.

Comment: Thanks. For some reasons, I actually have the same feeling about inversion in this case. It just doesn't sound "right" if I can say so.